# How to escape single quotes in Firebird 2.5 in where clause of select statement

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

How do I get this to work?

```
select * from table where column like '%situation = 'C'%'
```

Comment: do not use text values!!! use parameters - https://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To escape an apostrophe you need to double it see [manual](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-commons.html#fblangref25-commons-string-constant)

```
 select * from table where column like '%situation = ''C''%'
```